# Adverbial “tout” to mean “right”

Tags: locutions, tout-tous

I know that in adverbial phrases, “tout” means quite, very, right, all, etc.

Is it correct to use “tout” to mean “right” in contexts such as the following:

If I wanted to say “it’s right here,” after having found something I was looking for in a store, for example, could I say “c’est tout ici”? Or would it be “c’est par ici” (it’s over here)?

He’s right next to me = il est à tout côté de moi ?

I’ll be right back = je reviens tout de suite ?

I’m trying to get a handle on the many uses of “tout” and its various forms. I understand for the most part, but there are so many possibilities that my head spins sometimes.

Comment: I can't comment it out but you might say "il est tout à côté de moi" and not "il est à tout côté de moi"

Comment: Oops, I knew that, and made a typo in my original post. Thank you for pointing this out. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sometimes use "tout" to mean "right", it's partially true; (the translations come out of Harrap and Robert Collins, if nothing else is  mentioned)

- It's right at the top. : *C'est tout en haut.*
- It's right at the other end. : *C'est tout à l'autre bout.*
- I'll be right back. : *Je reviens tout de suite.*
- It's right in the middle. : *C'est au **beau** milieu.*
- It's right in front of you. : *C'est **droit** devant vous.*
- It's right behind you. : *C'est **juste** derrière vous.*
- It's right here. *C'est **juste** ici.* [ref](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/right+here)
- He's right next to me. : *Il est **juste** à côté de moi*. [ref](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/right%20next)

You can also say synonymously "*Il est tout à côté de moi.*", even  though  it's [not used as frequently](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tout+%C3%A0+c%C3%B4t%C3%A9+de+moi%2Cjuste+%C3%A0+c%C3%B4t%C3%A9+de+moi&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctout%20%C3%A0%20c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%20de%20moi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjuste%20%C3%A0%20c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%20de%20moi%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctout%20%C3%A0%20c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%20de%20moi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjuste%20%C3%A0%20c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%20de%20moi%3B%2Cc0).

"C'est par ici." means really "It's somewhere around here." but people will use this sentence sometimes to mean "It's right here."

Par ici : in these parts, over here, around here, hereabout, round here.  [ref](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/par%20ici)

Comment: It seems in your explanation that “droit,” as in “c’est droit devant vous,” could be related to “tout droit” which I know means “straight ahead” or “straight on.” This makes sense to me as your example means “straight/right ahead of you.” I hear “tout droit” when I’m using my GPS to find directions. J’ai un bon moment déclic !

Comment: I think I can also use “tout” as in my initial guess of “il est tout à côté de moi,” as well as your example. I actually saw this phrase here (in the second paragraph): https://www.thoughtco.com/tout-a-lheure-1371417

Comment: @tssmith2425 "J’ai un bon moment déclic ! " is not correct; I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, I meant simply “j’ai un déclic.” To have a brain wave. A moment where something clicks.

Comment: @tssmith2425 I see, it's really "J'ai eu un déclic.", it's modern French [reverso]( https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/j'ai+eu+un+déclic.html).

Comment: Oh! Thank you. I tried to use it in the present indicative to emphasize that it was happening in that moment

Comment: @tssmith2425 You mean a fleeting but strong conviction you had it right? Then maybe you're trying to say "j'ai eu un (bon) déclic **sur** le moment."

Comment: That’s exactly it